# Upload a document from a form into a SharePoint document library

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharepoint

The idea is that I have a form which I want to allow users to upload files into my SharePoint document library. I am just not just what to do after the 'HasFile' Statement. Some small snippets of my code below. I am just not sure how from the fileupload ID to get it into my document library. Please provide code.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />



<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Server side code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
      //????
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method could be used to upload Document into SharePoint Library:

```
/// <summary>
/// Uploads the specified file into a SharePoint Library
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">site url</param>
/// <param name="creds">Credentials</param>
/// <param name="listTitle">List Title</param>
/// <param name="fileName">File Name</param>
/// <param name="stream">File Stream</param>
private static void UploadFile(string url,string listTitle, string fileName, Stream stream)
{
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
    {


        var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fileName);

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, stream, true);

     }
 }
```

> Note: If you need to pass [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icredentials.aspx) , use
>   [ClientRuntimeContext.Credentials property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientruntimecontext.credentials%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to set the
>   authentication information for the client context as demonstrated
>   below:
>
> ```
> clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
> ```

Usage

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
 {

     UploadFile(webUrl, listTitle, FileUpload1.FileName, FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
 }
```